# Как защитить себя при создании сайта на заказ?

Tags: юридические-аспекты, веб-программирование

Само собой первая мысль - как минимум заключить контракт. Но, все таки, как еще можно себя защитить? Встраивание backdore в сайт - это же не очень красиво?
Кто как действует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По белому: Работать через гарант.
По черному: [ссылка](http://fuckyear.ru/?p=37)

Comment: Через гарант - это как, если не секрет?)

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам backdoor не понравился? Плохой клиент о нем узнает только в последний момент, хороший о нем вообще ничего не знает. Главное - выпилить вредоносный код по окончании работы.

Вариант два: писать сайт на своем хостинге, а после оплаты переносить на хостинг заказчика.

Comment: поддерживаю вариант два. показываю прототип сайта на своем хостинге, и если клиент согласен - то он оплачивает, а я все переношу к нему.

Comment: @ling, будет ли клиент слушать оправдания "я собирался удалить этот backdoor, он только для страховки", если всё-таки узнает про него?

Comment: @xEdelweiss, это будет хорошим поводом попросить у клиента еще денег за удаление backdoor :)

Comment: Насчет своего хостинга догадывался. А насчет бэкдора... В общих чертах понимаю, что да как. А хорошая идея (чтоб никто другой не догадался как можно через него навредить, например) как реализовать - в голову не приходит. Есть ли где-нибудь основные принципы/примеры?

Answer (score 0):

Разработка сайта на своём хостинге до завершения. И републикация его на хостинге заказчика, после проплаты второй части по договору.
Опытом научен работать по 50% предоплате.
—————
Второй способ \ выдача паролей от хостинга и ftp - после полной оплаты за проект.
Если оплата не поступает, то лично у меня запрограммирован web-locker, с opacity 0.7, на центральную страницу сайта с напоминанием о непогашенной задолженности по проекту.
————
Применять второй способ приходилось лишь один раз в жизни.
По первому работаю постоянно.